# Form Validation - Email/telephone number

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have a problem with a validate function, I made it in one function only and I want to add validation of email such as @ and numbers 1-9. How do I add it?

html:

```
<form onsubmit="return validate();" name="formValidation">
    <label>First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" /><br /><br />
    <label>Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastName" /><br /><br />
    <label>E_mail:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Email" /><br /><br />
    <label>Confirm E_mail:</label>
    <input type="text" name="confirmEmail" /><br /><br />
    <label>Address:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Address" /><br /><br />
    <label>Telephone nr:</label>
    <input type="text" name="telephoneNr" /><br /><br />
    <br />
    <p>submit your form: </p><input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

js:

```
function validate(){
    if(document.formValidation.firstName.value == "" ||
    document.formValidation.lastName.value == "" ||
    document.formValidation.Email.value == "" ||
    document.formValidation.confirmEmail.value == "" ||
    document.formValidation.Address.value == "" ||
    document.formValidation.telephoneNr.value == "")
    {
        alert("Please fill all the boxes before submitting!");
        return false;
    } else {
        alert('Your form has been submitted!');
    }

}
```

Comment: THis post might be able to help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/email-validation.php:

This function will validate an email using javascript:

```
function ValidateEmail(mail)   
{  
 if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(mail))  
  {  
    return (true)  
  }  
    alert("You have entered an invalid email address!")  
    return (false)  
}
```

To validate a phone number:

```
function validatePhone(phone) {
    var error = "";
    var stripped = phone.replace(/[\(\)\.\-\ ]/g, '');

   if (stripped == "") {
        error = "You didn't enter a phone number.";
    } else if (isNaN(parseInt(stripped))) {
        phone = "";
        error = "The phone number contains illegal characters.";

    } else if (!(stripped.length == 10)) {
        phone = "";
        error = "The phone number is the wrong length. Make sure you included an area code.\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: how do I put it in my html code? I'm new to this and I want to know how to do this for future

Comment: You can add these functions to the <script> tags on your html (or separate .js file). Same place that you have your validate function. On your validate function you can add the logic to verify document.formValidation.Email.value and document.formValidation.telephoneNr.value. You would pass these values to the functions listed above.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a regular expression. There are a very large number of questions already describing how to do this:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+regex+phone+number+email

Answer (score 0):

I can give you an example function I've used. It's not perfect, but it's quick and easy to set  in your environment with minimal editing:

```
function mail_check(){
var email   = document.getElementById(\'email\').value;
var email_check = email.split("@");
if (email_check[1]){var email_check2 = email_check[1].split(".");}
if (!email_check[1] || !email_check2[0] || !email_check2[1]) {
document.getElementById(\'mail_status\').innerHTML = "<font color=red>Invalid Email address!</font>";
return false;}
else if (email_check[1] && email_check2[0] && email_check2[1]) {
document.getElementById(\'mail_status\').innerHTML = "<font color=green>Valid Email address!</font>";
return true;}
}
```

I guess it's obvious I have an empty span element, that gets altered live with an OnKeyUp js event (basically onkeyup calls the function, which creates the illusion the systems checks live... although it does, so I guess it's not an illusion after all - hah!)

Hope that helps. In case you want further help let me know!

Cheers!

Comment: I don't know how to call this function in my html code, I'm new to javascript and I have no ideamost of the time what I'm doing. Any help masters of js?:)

Comment: just add to your input field `onkeyup="mail_check()"`
it should look something like `<input type=varchar size=... style="..." onkeyup="mail_check()" ... >` - that should work :)

Answer (score 0):

This is quite common task, and way you trying solve it is what is was like a la 2008, hey it is 2013 almost here)

the first try to look up the [regExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to solve it in this way.

But yeh, why not use HTML5 [form validation](http://caniuse.com/form-validation) and [Modernizir](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/forms-validation.js) for fallback on an older/unsupported browsers.

You will got native support for all modern browsers, which is faster than JS, plus well writen js which will care about it in a proper way for ones who by some reason do not have support for `form validations`.